# Docker container volume binding on Google Cloud

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I have a small issue. So I have built docker images that I need to be running on Google Cloud, and my issue is that running them requires two volume binding flags. And I can't seem to figure it out how they are passed as container arguments inside Cloud Run in the Google Cloud console. This is the command if I were to run the docker image locally:

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /tmp:/tmp --gpus all -it --rm --name ner  -p 5000:5000 electra_mlflow
```

Excuse me for the line being long, but the only thing from it that matters are the two volume binding arguments. I've read the documentation for Google Cloud and I couldn't figure it out. Then I ran into this blog that states that Google Cloud doesn't allow volumes, but proposes a workaround using Secret Manager. https://medium.com/google-cloud/mount-a-file-as-a-volume-in-cloud-run-facc74c02cc6

I'm however nowhere nearer how I would use this workaround for my application, specifically: **what string would I save in secrets for this to work?** Also, as I understand it, there's a file size limit to the workaround which is a problem, but a solvable one for me.

Comment: My comment is complimenting @DazWilin's good answer. Cloud Run does not run under Docker and most of the Docker style options are not available. If you need volume mounts (persistent storage), I recommend using Compute Engine and local persistent storage. Cloud Run is designed to be a stateless HTTP Request/Response system with no background threads or tasks. Since you need to store state, use a service that provides that feature. Otherwise, you will be hacking a well-designed service to fit your requirements with the associated headaches and reduced service reliability.

Comment: Why do you need to mount the /tmp and the docker.sock volume? What's the requirement of your container? The /tmp is useless, because it's a stateless environment and you won't be able to keep the /tmp data, it's ephemeral. The docker.sock is the docker configuration that won't be take into account on Cloud Run (because Docker is not used at runtime). So, why these requirements?

Answer (score 3):

Cloud Run is a so-called "serverless" platform and you do not have access to the underlying host running the container(s).

For this reason, there's no equivalent of volume-mounting the host's directories into the container as is achieved with Docker when running `docker run` with `--volumes`.

There are various ways that your Cloud Run service could access e.g. external files. Using a Secret Manager is one way though this approach is generally most applicable to the use of secrets.

If you want a Cloud Run service to be able to access files as if these were on a local e.g. Linux machine, you may want to evaluate NFS server solutions. These enable your Cloud Run instances to operate is if the files were available locally as you achieve with `docker run ... --volumes=...`.

See:

- [Google Cloud Filestore](https://cloud.google.com/filestore) (not to be confused with [Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore))
- [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage) (providing object storage not NFS) but when combined w/ [gcs-fuse](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) which makes GCS act like NFS

I encourage you to research the options thoroughly and be mindful of alternative (!) ways to achieve these results.

For example, you could:

- Bundle the `/tmp` directory contents into the image
- Deploy your container to a Compute Engine VM running a container runtime.
- &c.

Comment: how about this workaround? https://medium.com/google-cloud/mount-a-file-as-a-volume-in-cloud-run-facc74c02cc6

Comment: I'm not going to recommend solutions that I've not tried. I'm leery of shoe-horning one solution into another. Secret Manager is best for secrets. Honestly, I think you should determine what specifically you're trying to achieve and then determine an optimal solution. The `docker.sock` aside, you may be able to simply bundle your files into the image.